# AES_DECRYPT Requires Cast?

Tags: mysql, encryption

I'm trying to use the `AES_ENCRYPT` and `AES_DECRYPT` functions. I've found an answer to my initial question which was how to decrypt the encrypted string, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556375/how-to-use-aes-encrypt-and-aes-decrypt-in-mysql. I'm not sure why the `char(50)` is needed though, nor what to do since my string can be longer than `50` characters. Should I use `char(65535)`?

This returns the encrypted string as expected:

```
SELECT 'test' as original, 
AES_ENCRYPT('test', UNHEX(SHA2('This Is Cool',512))) as encrypted, 
CAST(AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('test', UNHEX(SHA2('This Is Cool',512))), UNHEX(SHA2('This Is Cool',512))) as char(50)) as decrypted
```

[image: Correct Return]

this does not:

```
SELECT 'test' as original, 
AES_ENCRYPT('test', UNHEX(SHA2('This Is Cool',512))) as encrypted, 
AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('test', UNHEX(SHA2('This Is Cool',512))), UNHEX(SHA2('This Is Cool',512))) as decrypted
```

[image: Incorrect Return]

Comment: Don't fool yourself, obfuscation (with that SHA2 call) makes it harder to type, but not harder to hack.

Comment: @RickJames It is only for GDPR compliance. The string being encrypted is just IP addresses which for some reason GDPR considers to be a property of an individual... or do you I can just pass the string to that function without the passphrase at all?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question:  "do you I can ...".  I use `AES_ENCRYPT('...', $passphrase)` where `$passphrase` is loaded from some hard to get place.  (More details depend on the environment -- language, web server, etc.)

Comment: @RickJames Sorry that was a large typo which I thought I had correct. Using `AES_ENCRYPT` and a salt (passphrase, loaded from a non web-accessible dir) is sufficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resume the situation for people who don’t want to follow the link to the original question on SO: the OP is querying a Mysql DB via an unspecified interface which (sensibly) refuses to show the values stored in `VARBINARY` fields with encrypted data, and (rather dumb-mindedly) still shows a `BLOB` label for the value returned by calling `AES_DECRYPT` on them. The answer given on SO was to cast those results as `CHAR(50)`, which from a DB perspective makes little sense, but in this way the interface shows the results as text and everybody is happy.

The question here is: *if I have to use `CHAR(50)`, how can I handle longer values?*

My answer is: you don’t say which interface you are using (your screenshots are not enough for me to recognize it), but I’d bet that if you cast as `CHAR` instead of `CHAR(50)` it still works and you have no size limits that you should care of. So:

```
SELECT 'test' AS original, 
        AES_ENCRYPT('test', UNHEX(SHA2('This Is Cool',512))) AS encrypted, 
        CAST(AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('test', UNHEX(SHA2('This Is Cool',512))), 
                                             UNHEX(SHA2('This Is Cool',512))) 
             AS CHAR) AS decrypted;
```

However, this is an interface question, not a DB engine question, and it is rather strange. I suspect the interface settings have been changed from the ones used when asking the first question, because now the strings which the interface thinks are binary are automatically displayed as `HEX`. Giving the first query to a commandline interface does not produce the results shown here. To get them from a commandline interface I have to write the second field as `HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('test', UNHEX(SHA2('This Is Cool',512))))`; similarly, the supposedly wrong result of the second query is simply `HEX('test')` instead of `'test'` because the interface does not know it is actually readable text. Casting it to `CHAR` should work.

Please be aware that all those conversions the interface is forcing you to perform are not needed when data is exchanged between different parts of your application.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. The direct interface doesn't require the `cast`. Another reason not to trust PHPmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit your configuration file in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` in order to display binary data as text:

```
[mysql]
binary-as-hex = false
```